# Convert Apache rewrite rules to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

How do I convert these rules from .htaccess (apache) to Nginx conf?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1-$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I use these rules to rewrite requests like:

```
/someurl1/ => someurl.html (/company/ to /company.html
/someurl1/someurl2/ => someurl-someurl2.html (/projects/3/ to /projects-3.html)
```

I've already tried this (doesn't work):

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
  rewrite ^/([^/]+)/$ /$1.html;
  rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1-$2.html;
}

try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following and it appears to work:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/$ /$1.html last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1-$2.html last;
    return 404;
}
```

The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` test is actually accomplished by the `try_files` directive.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: what about index.html?

Comment: By default `nginx` will execute an `index.html` file when presented with a URI ending with `/`. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.